# Is variable type the same as value type?

Tags: java, variables, int

If I write:

```
int x = 7;
```

Can we conclude that the value type of 7 is int and therefore the type of x is also int?

What is 'int' indicating here? That the value is int or that 7 is an int?

Comment: "Can we conclude that the value type of 7 is int and therefore the type of x is also int?" No, for example, the type of `x` could be `long`. "What is 'int' indicating here? " The type of `x`...

Comment: We can conclude that `7` is an `int` literal because the JLS says that it is. A `long` literal is written with a letter "l" suffix.

Comment: So when we write int x = 7 we are really just labeling the variable as an int correct?

Comment: You're declaring a variable, and explicitly telling the compiler it is of type `int`.

Comment: @Allan the expression `7` in Java source code has the type `int`. That is defined in the JLS. It can be explicitly converted to several other types, and explicitly using casts and method invocations to even more types.

Comment: @Allan The variable is an `int` because it was declared that way, and nobody has said anything different. The 7 is an `int` because of [JLS #3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int refers to x. It is indicating the type of the variable x. This is also informative of the type of the values that would be stored there.

```
  int x =7;
```

Consists of 2 parts.
One is:

```
   int x;
```

That declares  x as an int in this scope. This shows that int refers to x.
The other part of the expression is:

```
     x=7;
```

That actually assigns the int value 7 to x.Of course the assignment needs to be valid.So the value should be of a suitable type.
 It also would be valid to omit the assignment  in a program (if for example you do not use this variable.) 
On the other hand you cannot omit the declaration since java is strongly typed.
For example writing:

```
y=8;
```

Does not give enough information unless y is declared.
y could be for example an int , Integer , long or Long.
What y is depends on its declaration.

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that the variable `x` is of type `int`.

The expression `7` also happens to have type `int`, therefore the example is not that interesting.

Consider a more interesting example:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here, the compiler could infer that the type of `new ArrayList<>()` on the right hand side is `ArrayList<String>`. However, we might want to hide the concrete implementing class `ArrayList`, and instead declare `myList` to be of a more general type `List<String>`, which is a supertype of `ArrayList<String>`. This is useful if we want to prevent abstraction leak from the members of a class, or if we use `myList` as a local variable, and for some reason want to set it to an `LinkedList` later.

---

That's all I had to say on the question itself, but I want to give some context, and I want to argue that Java's current syntax is actually not too bad.

This syntax might seem verbose, one might think that one can often omit the type declaration on the left hand side. However, consider a language with stronger type inference.
For example, a closely related statically strongly typed language Scala tends to rely more on type inference. For example, if you write

```
var myList = List("foo", "bar")
```

it will automatically infer that `myList` is a variable of type `List[String]`.

But this often leads to unwanted results. For example, given the assignment

```
var myList = List.empty
```

the Scala compiler would happily infer that the right hand side is a `List[Nothing]`, where `Nothing` is a special type that signifies absurd impossible results "returned" by thrown Exceptions and Errors which break the normal program flow. You can't do anything with this variable. In order to make this variable useful, we have to write:

```
var myList: List[String] = List.empty
```

Now Scala compiler would understand that `myList` is supposed to be `List[String]`, which is more general than the type inferred from the right hand side. As you can see: now you have both `val` keyword and an additional `List[String]`-type declaration on the left hand side, which is not necessarily much shorter than the corresponding Java version. It is actually *longer*, despite all the fancy type-inference magic. So, Java's syntax for variable declarations is... OK, at least it's not trivial to make it much better.